# Haskell Data.Fixed.Binary status

Tags: haskell, fixed-point

There is a package in Hackage called Data.Fixed.Binary that I am interested in.  The problem I have is that it appears not to work with recent releases of base. I would like to know if there is a reason against having a this package.  Did I miss a different way to work with fixed point binary values in Haskell?

Comment: You can edit the `base` version in the cabal file and install it yourself.

Comment: Or try the `--allow-newer=base` option.

Comment: If you are going to follow Sibi's suggestion, you can conveniently get the sources from Hackage with `cabal unpack`.

Comment: Sibi.  Its not just a case of a cabal constraint.  The code, which I downloaded off the hackage page https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-point-0.5.0.1 does not type check in ghci.  Thanks for the hint though.